# How to space before and after a `minted` code block with bgcolor?

Tags: spacing, minted

I'm using `minted` to format code samples in my document, and I have set a `bgcolor` option to make them stand out.  By default (as in Harish's answer below) the code block will naturally have some margins above and below to separate the code from the paragraphs.  However, when I set a `bgcolor`, that goes away.  The question is: how can I get the colored background while also getting normal whitespace above and below the code block?  (Question has been edited since I narrowed down the problem to the case where `bgcolor` is set.)

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\setminted{bgcolor=light-gray}  % this line causes the problem

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1] Some text

\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}

Some text \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Are you placing the `minted` code in a float or not?

Comment: No, I didn't.  That would move it around to convenient places for TeX, like the bottom or top of the page, right?  I think I want to keep my code in line, just make sure it has a little breathing room.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe it's a bug in `minted`, because the internal `minted@colorbg` environment, used when the `bgcolor` option has been given, doesn't add vertical space above and below.

Here's a proposed fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{light-gray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\setminted{bgcolor=light-gray}  % this line causes the problem

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\minted@colorbg}{\noindent}{\medskip\noindent}{}{}
\apptocmd{\endminted@colorbg}{\par\medskip}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1] Some text

\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}

Some text \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why you want this but as such, minted is separated well enough as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1] Some text
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
Some text \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you insist, here is a way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\bigskip}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\bigskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1] Some text
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
Some text \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit:

Now the MWE is given and the solution still works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{2cm}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{2cm}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1] Some text

\begin{minted}[bgcolor=light-gray]{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}

Some text \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I was setting a `bgcolor` option for minted, and it seems to mess with this default behavior.  Insert this line into your example and you'll see that it takes away the spacing: `\setminted{bgcolor=red}`

Comment: @joeclark-phd: How do I know? From where did you get `\setminted`?. See the edit.

Comment: But suppose that you don't want a new paragraph to start after the code block? So `Some text \lipsum*[2]` would immediately follow `\end{minted}` without a blank line. When I do this with your code, the formatting gets messed up ("Some" is on the same line as the code and then there's the spacing before the rest of the paragraph).

Comment: @itzy: Try `\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\par\noindent}`.