# How to put space before and after an \inputminted code block with bgcolor?

Tags: minted

This is related to the question [How to space before and after a `minted` code block with bgcolor?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228058/how-to-space-before-and-after-a-minted-code-block-with-bgcolor)  There it is explained that there is a bug with minted which causes the space above and below a code block to disappear when you set a background colour.  A fix is given for the minted environment.  I want to fix the \inputminted command as well!  Unfortunately the same fix doesn't work as this is a command not an environment.

I thought I could fix it with \apptocmd and \pretocmd, but as the following minimal working example shows, \pretocmd does the right thing but \apptocmb gives the error "! Missing \endcsname inserted."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{bgcolor=blue!8}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\inputminted}{\par\vspace{1em}}{}{}
% The following line doesn't work
\apptocmd{\inputminted}{\par\vspace{1em}}{}{}

% These are the fixes given for the minted environment
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{1em}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\par\vspace{1em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.py}
n = 20
for i in range(n)
    print("Hello World")
\end{filecontents*}

\lipsum*[1]

% Here is where the problem lies.
\inputminted{python}{test.py}

\lipsum*[1]

% This bit of code works as it should
\begin{minted}{python}
n = 10
for i in range(n)
    print("Hello World")
\end{minted}

\lipsum*[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\inputminted` command is defined with an optional argument, so it's not patchable with `etoolbox`, unless you say

```
\expandafter\pretocmd\csname\string\inputminted\endcsname...
```

(see [How can I use \patchcmd with commands with optional arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24245/how-can-i-use-patchcmd-with-commands-with-optional-arguments))

The package `xpatch` does the necessary bits by itself.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\inputminted}{\par\vspace{1em}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\inputminted}{\par\vspace{1em}}{}{}
```

[image]