# Beamer's \only animations break layout intra-animation with multicol

Tags: beamer, multicol, animations, layout

I am typesetting code with minted inside a `multicols` environment together with Beamer's `\only` animations. That leads to inconsistent layout spacing between the animated frames.

### Demo Video

[image: GIF screencast of the problem]
(click if you don't see a GIF animation)

### MWE

For the MWE you first need to save the files from this post's appendix.
The problem is reproducible with text files of different lengths, too, albeit not that clearly anymore. If somebody finds an easy way to embed those files into the code here without cluttering the whole page, feel free to comment that.
.

```
% !TEX TS-program = latexmk -xelatex -shell-escape -silent -latexoption="-synctex=1" -f %
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%
% First download casestudy1.txt and casestudy2.txt from the appendix of
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/540969/38074, then compile!
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,hyperref={bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand\supertiny{\fontsize{2.5}{3}\selectfont}
\newmintedfile[casestudyFile]{text}{firstline=2,breaklines=true,breakanywhere=true,fontsize=\supertiny,frame=none,linenos=false}
\newcommand{\typesetCaseStudy}[2]{%
    \begin{multicols}{5}
        {\supertiny
            \casestudyFile{#1}%
            \only<1>{\casestudyFile{#2}}%
            \only<2>{{\usebeamercolor[bg]{block title alerted}\casestudyFile{#2}}}%
            \only<3->{\textcolor{white}{\casestudyFile{#2}}}%
        }
    \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}{Case Study}
        \typesetCaseStudy{casestudy1.txt}{casestudy2.txt}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \structure{Before:} 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Foo
                \item Bar
            \end{itemize}
            \item<3-> \structure{After:} Baz
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

### Appendix

**castestudy1.txt:**

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
```

**casestudy2.txt:**

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
```

Comment: What should be the order of appearance of the blocks ? The current output seems unlikely

Comment: @BambOo I am afraid I do not completely get your question. The use case is that casestudy1.txt contains some source code A (the presentation talks about) and casestudy2.txt some source code B. Now the slide should show off that B is redundant and can be auto-generated from A.

Comment: What I mean is that at the moment `typesetCaseStudy` outputs : casestudy1 all the time + casestudy1 on frame 1 only + casestudy2 on frame 2 only + nothing, is that what you want ?

Comment: @BambOo Ah, good catch! I corrected it.

Comment: Just updated my answer. See if it works for you

Comment: Anys news on this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (probably not final) solution based on [egreg's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261262/141947)

**EDIT** After your correction of the definition of `\typesetCaseStudy` I  believe everything works as expected using

```
\newcommand{\typesetCaseStudy}[2]{%
        \begin{multicols}{5}
                \casestudyFile{#1}%
                \only<1>{\casestudyFile{#2}}%
                \only<2>{{\color{blockred}\casestudyFile{#2}}}%
                \only<3->{{\color{white}\casestudyFile{#2}}}%
        \end{multicols}
    }
```

```
% !TEX TS-program = latexmk -xelatex -shell-escape -silent -latexoption="-synctex=1" -f %
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%
% First download casestudy1.txt and casestudy2.txt from the appendix of
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/540969/38074, then compile!
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,hyperref={bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{casestudy1.txt}
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{casestudy2.txt}
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttest
\end{filecontents*}

\usebeamercolor{block title alerted}
\colorlet{blockred}{bg}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\inputminted}{\vspace{-1ex}}{}{}

\newcommand\supertiny{\fontsize{2.5}{3}\selectfont}
\newmintedfile[casestudyFile]{text}{firstline=2,breaklines=true,breakanywhere=true,fontsize=\supertiny,frame=none,linenos=false}
\newcommand{\typesetCaseStudy}[2]{%
    \begin{multicols}{5}
            \casestudyFile{#1}%
            \only<1>{\casestudyFile{#2}}%
            \only<2>{{\color{blockred}\casestudyFile{#2}}}%
            \only<3->{{\color{white}\casestudyFile{#2}}}%
    \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}{Case Study}
        \typesetCaseStudy{casestudy1.txt}{casestudy2.txt}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \structure{Before:} 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Foo
                \item Bar
            \end{itemize}
            \item<3-> \structure{After:} Baz
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]