# Adjust top and bottom margins using minted

Tags: minted, syntax-highlighting, lstlisting

I've been using the `listings` package with the following setup to produce a compact layout of code samples:

```
\lstset{
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true,
framextopmargin=50pt,framexleftmargin=30pt,framexbottommargin=-5pt
}
```

How would one control the top and bottom margins for `minted`? It doesn't have the same options.

Comment: Possibly you are looking for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228058/120578. If it solves your problem, please tell us to mark as a duplicate.

Comment: I think my problem is different because I'm not using any background colors.

Comment: Check the answer please

Comment: `minted` basically uses a slightly modified version of `trivlist`. By wrapping it with `tcolorbox` features might be the simplest way to achieve your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\medskip}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\medskip}


\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1] Some text

\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}

Some text \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

It is @user11232's answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228062/120578) but without background colors.

Output:

[image]

Comment: How would I use it to adjust the top and bottom margins?

Comment: You are right... It didn't worked with changes... I edited... You can change `\medskip` to `\bigskip` or `\smallskip`.. or even `\medskip\smallskip` or `\vspace{1cm}` etc