# Remove whitespace before and after minted

Tags: minted

I am including Rust code into my Latex files by using minted. I am mostly showing 1-3 lines of code, with an explanation afterwards. So the large gaps before and after `\begin{minted}{rust}...\end{minted}` sections leaf my pages ripped.

I am using the following command for the one-lineres, they are fine due to not having any whitespaces around.
Unfortunately, it removes indentations and is therefore not suited for multi-line functions:
`\newcommand{\rust}[1]{\mintinline{rust}{#1}}`

How can I get the behaviour of mintinline for a multiline function without any whitespaces above or under my code?

```
\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand{\rust}[1]{\mintinline{rust}{#1}}
\begin{document}
This is a text directly above the code
\begin{minted}[autogobble]{rust}
if 5 > 3 {
    var = 3;
}
\end{minted}
This is a text which should come directly under the code.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Five years ago the opposite question was asked in [How to space before and after a `minted` code block with bgcolor?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228058/how-to-space-before-and-after-a-minted-code-block-with-bgcolor), where `minted` blocks with a background color did not have any vertical space. This issue has since been fixed, but for the current question you can reverse the answer there, i.e., instead of *adding* `\medskip` to the box with the background color you can *remove* the `\medskip` using `etoolbox`. You probably don't want a background color, but setting `white` looks the same as no color at all.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% replace \medskip before and after the box with nothing, i.e., remove it
\patchcmd{\minted@colorbg}{\medskip}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endminted@colorbg}{\medskip}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\noindent This is a text directly above the code
\begin{minted}[autogobble]{rust}
if 5 > 3 {
    var = 3;
}
\end{minted}
This is a text which should come directly under the code.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\noindent This is a text directly above the code
\begin{minted}[autogobble,bgcolor=white]{rust}
if 5 > 3 {
    var = 3;
}
\end{minted}
This is a text which should come directly under the code.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Result side by side:

[image]